# Handling Tinyint in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to post data from an online form into a database, and some of the fields on the form are checkboxes. I originally defined the datatype for the checkboxes as BIT, but after selecting a checkbox, and submitting the form, when I look in the database, the values are all 'b'. I then set the datatype to BOOLEAN, and it switched itself to TINYINT. However, after selecting a checkbox/submitting the form, the values in the database are all '0'. I'm expecting to see a '1' which would correspond to the checkbox that has been selected, but that isn't happening. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that you're passing the `checked` value of the checkbox into your data. Checkboxes don't use true/false, but rather `"checked"` or empty. You can do something like this:

```
$value = ($checked == "checked" ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are, at some point here, converting a string to an integer. When your do this in PHP, chances are the result will be 0 ([see this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)). I'm not sure about MySQL, but I suspect it handles the operation in a broadly similar way.

The way to deal with this, I would say, is to have your checkboxes defined like this:

```
<input name="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Then, in PHP, get the value that you insert into the database like this:

```
$myCheckBoxIsChecked = (!empty($_POST['mycheckbox'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

Then, you can use `$myCheckBoxIsChecked` straight in your query, with no sanitisation - because you know that it can only ever have a value of `1` or `0`.